# Effective ways for asynchronous game server implementation on C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, networking, server

I've been developing pet project - framework for MMO servers. Just for skills improvement. There are a lot of tutorials but usually its doesn't contain details.

Using async/await.

```cs
async void StartReceive()
{
    while (mTcpClient.Connected)
    {
        var stream = mTcpClient.GetStream();
        try
        {

            //read header
            byte[] headerBuffer = new byte[sizeof(int)];
            int read = 0;
            while (read < sizeof(int))
            {
                read += await stream.ReadAsync(headerBuffer, 0, sizeof(int) - read).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            //read body
            read = 0;
            int messageSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(headerBuffer, 0);
            byte[] messageBuffer = new byte[messageSize];

            while (read < messageSize)
            {
                read += await stream.ReadAsync(messageBuffer, read, messageSize - read).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            //parse and proccess message
            ProcessMessage(messageBuffer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}

async void ProcessMessage(byte[] buffer)
{
    var message = await ParseMessageAsync(buffer).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (OnReceived != null)
        OnReceived(this, message);
}

Task<IMessage> ParseMessageAsync(byte[] buffer)
{
    return Task<IMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        var header = MessageHeader.Parser.ParseFrom(buffer);
        return MessagingReflection.Descriptor.MessageTypes[header.Type].Parser.ParseFrom(header.Data);
    });
}
```

If my understanding correct, two methods will be generated and called in unknown thread from the pool. The first method includes "read body" and "parse and proccess" parts, the second - "parse and proccess".
It means that when the reading of sizeof(int) is ended, some thread will be free and some other thread will be runned to proceed reading.

- Is it better to proceed reading of message body synchronously in
  thread where result of reading header was done? (I mean using
  synchronous read for body, after asynchronous read for header). In my
  case messages should be quite simple and compact. But it's
  interesting for any cases.
- ProcessMessage runs task which awaiting for Google.Protobuf parsing. Then the OnReceived delegate will be invoked. If a handler are doing some heavy work, the client can disconnect from host. What ways are there for correctly stopping tasks if client was disconnected?
- I have two delegates - OnReceived and OnDisconnected. The first called when full message buffer received, the second is called when exception was thrown in StartReceived(). This delegates assined in the same time, but in the catch block the OnDisconnected is always equal to null! I can't understand why (the OnReceived is still not null in this case, but OnDisconnect is gone!). Can someone explain why it's happening?

(Assigning delegates example)

```
public class ServerTest
{
    List<Client> mClients = new List<Client>();
    ConectionService mConnectionService = new ConectionService(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 5555));

    public ServerTest()
    {
        mConnectionService.OnClientConnected += OnClientConnected;
        mConnectionService.Start();
    }

    public void OnClientConnected(Client client)
    {
        client.OnDisconnected += OnDisconnected;
        client.OnReceived += OnDataReceived;
        mClients.Add(client);
    }

    public void OnDisconnected(Client client)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server: client disconnected");
    }

    public void OnDataReceived(Client client, IMessage message)
    {
        var res = new LoginResponce() { Status = true };
        client.SendMessage(LoginResponce.Descriptor, res);
    }
}
```

Comment: `ProcessMessage` looks like it wants to be a TPL [Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx)  block, eg TransformBlock. And `async void` is only meant for event handlers or similar functions.